# Convert phonenumber(string) to integer number (Revised)

Tags: java

**Question**

Write a method that returns a number, given an uppercase letter, as follows.

```
int getNumber (char uppercaseLetter)
```

Write a test program that prompts the user to enter a phone number as a string. The input number may contain letters. The program translates a letter (uppercase or lowercase) to a digit and leaves all other characters intact.

**Sample run from textbook**

> ```
> Enter a string: 1-800-Flowers
> 1-800-3569377
>
> Enter a string: 1800flowers
> 18003569377
> ```

**Here is what I have so far**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment {

public static int correspondingNumber(char uppercaseLetter){

    int correspondingNumber=0;
    switch (uppercaseLetter)
    {
    case 'A': 
    case 'B':
    case 'C': correspondingNumber=2;  break;
    case 'D': 
    case 'E': 
    case 'F': correspondingNumber=3;  break;
    case 'G': 
    case 'H': 
    case 'I': correspondingNumber=4;  break;
    case 'J':
    case 'K':
    case 'L': correspondingNumber=5;  break;
    case 'M': 
    case 'N':   
    case 'O': correspondingNumber=6;  break;
    case 'P': 
    case 'Q': 
    case 'R': 
    case 'S': correspondingNumber=7;  break;
    case 'T': 
    case 'U': 
    case 'V': correspondingNumber=8;  break;
    case 'W': 
    case 'X': 
    case 'Y': 
    case 'Z': correspondingNumber=9;  break;
        

}
    return correspondingNumber;

}
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String num;
char num1 = 0;
System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
num = input.next();
num.toUpperCase();
int i=0;
while(i!=num.length()){
num1=num.charAt(i);


}
     
System.out.print(correspondingNumber(num1));     
     
    
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is simply dumping a problem on us with no effort to solve the problem oneself.

Comment: Suggestions to help you get better answers: 1) get rid of the image link and **type out** any and all requirements. 2) format your code so that it is *easily* readable. 3) Don't simply post requirements and code without any explanation. If you need specific help, then please ask a complete and specific question or questions. Please remember that you're asking volunteers to put in free work, so you'll want to make it as easy as possible for them to do this.

Comment: And also, please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions.

Comment: Can you help me with the program than? I appreciate it.

Comment: I would be more than happy to, but of course after you've followed the suggestions listed above. The first thing that I'd suggest is that you don't leave your main method empty. That's where the program starts, and if it's empty, the program won't do much of anything at all.

Comment: I gave the algorithm kind of in answer.. you give a try.. I can help you to make it work.. It also helps me learn things

Comment: @RamPrakash: just please don't spoon-feed a code solution. Else you're not teaching how to code but rather how to beg.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for your suggestion.. I'm not spoon feeding. That's why I gave pseudo code kind of algorithm not the source code :).

Comment: @RamPrakash: and thank you. 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

steps need tobe done

1. scan input let's say as String
2. Convert string to character array (srcArray)
3. change method return of correspondingNumber to Char
4. default return to input and apply switch case
5. call method correspondingNumber, store return char in stringbuilder or Array of Char array
6. repeat step-5 until character array(srcArray) is completely processed
7. print the output

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment {
    // changed return type
    public static char correspondingNumber(char uppercaseLetter) {

        char correspondingNumber = uppercaseLetter;// default the return value
                                                    // to input
        switch (uppercaseLetter) {
        case 'A':
        case 'B':
        case 'C':
            correspondingNumber = '2';
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'E':
        case 'F':
            correspondingNumber = '3';
            break;
        case 'G':
        case 'H':
        case 'I':
            correspondingNumber = '4';
            break;
        case 'J':
        case 'K':
        case 'L':
            correspondingNumber = '5';
            break;
        case 'M':
        case 'N':
        case 'O':
            correspondingNumber = '6';
            break;
        case 'P':
        case 'Q':
        case 'R':
        case 'S':
            correspondingNumber = '7';
            break;
        case 'T':
        case 'U':
        case 'V':
            correspondingNumber = '8';
            break;
        case 'W':
        case 'X':
        case 'Y':
        case 'Z':
            correspondingNumber = '9';
            break;

        }
        return correspondingNumber;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num;
        char num1 = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        num = input.next();
        num.toUpperCase();
        int i = 0;
        while (i != num.length()) {
            num1 = num.charAt(i);
            System.out.print(correspondingNumber(num1)); // moved print
                                                            // statement to
                                                            // appropriate place
            i++; // iterate loop
        }

        input.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: I can able to run it and got Enter a string: 1800FLOWERS
18003569377

Comment: Can some one confirm my code?